# Private variable returns blank when readed, although it is set in a function

Tags: php

I have a class to create forms and a function that gets the form name form action and form type from the view files. It works fine and as expected, but when I call those variables in another function to create the actual form and to add the values to the  they return as blank.

```
class Form {
     private $formname;
     private $formaction;
     private $formtype;

function Form($form_name, $actionfile, $formtype) {
            $this->formname = $form_name;
            $this->formaction = $actionfile;
            $this->formtype = $formtype;
        }
```

This is where the functions values get stored in the private variables.

When I try to call them in another function they return as blank.

```
function formstart() {
$enc = 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
$returnstring = '<form name="' . $this->formname . '" id="' . $this->formname . '" ' . $enc . ' method="' . $this->formtype . '"  action="' . $this->formaction . '">';
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Nothing obvious. Present a _testcase_.

Comment: I am starting a form the view file with the following command: `{formstart:searchform:{url:(search/redir)}:POST}` from which the first function `Form ()` reads the values, and they display correctly, just can't get to read them in the 2nd function `formstart()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your class must be namespaced to use that constructor function. Instead, use the method `__construct()`

```
class Form {
     private $formname;
     private $formaction;
     private $formtype;

    function __construct($form_name, $actionfile, $formtype) {
        $this->formname = $form_name;
        $this->formaction = $actionfile;
        $this->formtype = $formtype;
    }
}
```

**[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)**

Comment: Tried __construct too. Still getting blank values.

Comment: Where are you getting blank values? You need to show us more context of your code.

Comment: Again, present a _testcase_.

Comment: I am getting blank values in the 2nd function, I need to read the values generated in the first function `Form()` and pass them to the 2nd function `startform()` when I try to call them with `$this->formname` it returns nothing.
The form displays as this:
`<form id="" action="" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="">`

Answer (score 1):

You're writing PHP 4.x OOP.

Try this:

```
class Form {

  private $formname;
  private $formaction;
  private $formtype;

  public function __construct($form_name, $action_file, $form_type) {
      $this->formname = $form_name;
      $this->formaction = $action_file;
      $this->formtype = $form_type;
  }

  public function formstart() {
      $enc = 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
      return '<form name="' . $this->formname . '" id="' . $this->formname . '" ' . $enc . ' method="' . $this->formtype . '"  action="' . $this->formaction . '">';
  }
}

$f = new Form('name', 'action', 'type');
echo $f->formstart();
```

Comment: Yes this one works, but I will have to change it in my view files, which are more than 30. Isn't there another way to do it ? As i mentioned in a comment I call the formstart function with `{formstart:searchform:{url:(search/redir)}:POST}`